# Line 29, in " <module> s.sendall(message)" TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x

```
import socket
import sys

try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except socket.error:
    print ('Failed to create socket')
    sys.exit();

print ('Socket Created', s)

host = 'www.google.com'
port = 80

try:
    remote_ip = socket.gethostbyname(host)
except socket.gaierror:
    print ('Hostname could not be resolved. Exiting')
    sys.exit()
print ('Ip address of "' + host + '" is: ' + remote_ip )

s.connect((remote_ip, port))

print ('Socket Connected to ' + host + ' on ip ' + remote_ip)

message = 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n'

try:
    s.sendall(message)
except socket.error:
    print ('Send Failed')
    sys.exit()

print ('Message send successfully')
reply = s.recv(4096)
print ('reply')
```

Comment: Could you please review the title, formatting and content of this question. You may find it useful to visit the help centre where there is guidance on asking questions.

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3, `str` is a unicode string, which could have a wide variety of byte representations. Strings are unicode by default.

To get a plain byte string, you can prefix the string with `b`, such as `b'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n'`. You can also use the `encode` method of a unicode string to get a specific encoding.

To learn more about Unicode, you should probably read the [Python 3 Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/unicode.html).